# Should I update state in another state update, should i or shouldn't i?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 states, one is set from API response and other on when API response changes a particular threshold and I set it and clear it after a timeout, I use a hook to achieve the same.

So I want to know which is a better approach,

```js
const [data, setData] = useState();
const [thresholdChanged, setThresholdChanged] = useState();
// I clear thresholdChanged message after 5 seconds
useEffect(() => {
  if(thresholdChanged !== undefined) {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => setThresholdChanged(undefined), TIMEOUT)
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  return undefined;
}, [thresholdChanged])
```

Now setting the data I have 2 options
First one will never recreate the `update` method but calls another setter inside the first setter, is it valid pattern?

```js
const update = useCallback((newData) => {
   setData((currentData) => {
     if(currentData < SOME_VALUE && newData > SOME_VALUE) {
       setThresholdChanged(true)
     }
     return newData;
   })
}, [])
```

or should I go with the second one which will recreate the method every time the data gets updated

```
const update = useCallback((newData) => {
   if(data < SOME_VALUE && newData > SOME_VALUE) {
       setThresholdChanged(true)
   }
   setData(newData)
}, [data])
```

Which one is a better approach and why?

NOTE: Code has been simplified for asking the question.

Comment: have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653983/does-calling-setter-of-usestate-hook-inside-if-statement-imply-breaking-rules-of/58654394#58654394

Comment: What will be calling the update method?

Comment: @cbdev420 API polling would give me a new value and on a response would call update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go with option #1 for two reasons:

- It's good practice to access the `currentState` (I usually call it `prevState`) using the `setState` function. It ensures that you'll be reading a fresh value from state.
- Since it will not be recreated on every `data` change, you'll be able to use `React.memo()` on components that receive the `update` method as `props`

```
const update = useCallback((newData) => {
   setData((currentData) => {
     if(currentData < SOME_VALUE && newData > SOME_VALUE) {
       setThresholdChanged(true)
     }
     return newData;
   })
}, [])
```

Comment: My concern is with calling another setter inside the first setter, is that a good approach or not but generally I like fewer updates to the components as well.

Comment: I guess that this wouldn't be a problem (hurts readability, imo). But to avoid calling a setState inside another, why don't you move the treshold logic into a useEffect?

Comment: Instead of trigger the tresholdchanged state. You could have an effect that would depend on the 'data' state and would set the timeout based on that directly. Withou the need for an intermediate state like 'tresholdChanged'

Comment: say `thresholdChanged` would be true only when value moves through the barrier, say if the value update like 1,2,3,4,5,6... and SOME_VALUE is  5, when an update happens above 5, will get thresholdChanged to true. If I rely on the effect I would have to have another state to keep old values which I don't want to do.

Comment: @Neo you don't need a state to hold old values. Use a `useRef` instead. It keeps its value across renders just like state. The only difference is that it does not trigger re-renders